# How to post to any facebook wall from android app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook Development. I am a bit stuck.
Mostly the questions which people have asked is regarding posting to "me/feed" wall. But
I want to use my android application to post a message to "any" facebook wall like say a company's wall that "I like this product". Can you please tell me how I can do that.
For doing this I have created my App ID and I use that while posting. The thing is I am able to post it to my wall when I give facebookConnector.postMessageOnWall("me/feed", "I like this product"); But when I want to post it to some company's wall let us say Samsung India wall I replace "me/feed" with "samsungIN?fref=ts" because the URL of Samsung India is "http://www.facebook.com/samsungIN?fref=ts" But when I do this I get this error:
"error": {"message":"(#210) Subject must be a page.", "type":"OAuthException","code", 210}}

The code which I use is as follows:

```
private static final String FACEBOOK_APPID = "";
private static final String FACEBOOK_PERMISSION = "publish_stream";
facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector(FACEBOOK_APPID, this, getApplicationContext(), new String[] {FACEBOOK_PERMISSION});
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APPID);
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.postToFaceBook){
        String response = facebook.request("samsungIN?fref=ts/feed", parameters,"POST");
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 do not delete and repost ... you should update old question! ... anyway read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme does `?` can be part of path ?

Comment: Hi I dont know how this will help!!

Comment: try to ged rid of query string from url ...

Answer (score 0):

Remove ?fref=ts

This portion is not needed, the call should be

`samsungIN/feed`

Comment: Hi, One small hitch. It works for Samsung India wall (http://www.facebook.com/samsungIN?fref=ts) when I give "samsungIN/feed" and it also works for LG USA Mobile (http://www.facebook.com/LGUSAMobile?fref=ts) when I give "LGUSAMobile/feed" but it does not work for LG India (http://www.facebook.com/lgindiapage?fref=ts) when I give "lgindiapage/feed". Any idea why?

Comment: @TapasDixit LG India doesn't offer users the option to write on their wall